# JS pass array values as separate arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a CSV file of some data and for each line, I split it by the comma to get an array `vals`.

Now I want to pass `vals` into a function, but **"flatten"** it (without changing the function because it is used elsewhere)

```
function foo(x, y, z) {
     return x*y*z:
}
    
var vals = [1, 3, 4];
//want a shortcut to this (this would be a nightmare with like 20 values)
foo(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2]);
```

**Edit:

Sorry, kind of left out a big detail. I only want part of the array, like the first 10 elements of a 12 element array. Any shortcut for this?**

Comment: In JavaScript, you don't need to specify ``var`` for the arguments. ``function foo(x, y,  z)`` works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator; if you are using es6.

```
var vals = [1,2,34,5]
foo(...vals)
```

Or you could also use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
function foo(a,b,c,d,e) {
  console.log(a,b,c,d,e)
}
var vals = [1,2,3,4,5]
foo.apply(null, vals)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need `var` in the parameters,

second, you may use the spread operator

```js
function foo(x, y, z) {
  return x * y * z;
}
var vals = [1, 3, 4];
console.log(foo(...vals));
```

reference: [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)